# Update SQL Database Definition with Local XSD

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2005, xsd

I'm trying to retrieve an `XSD` definition of the tables and their datatypes, key-constraints from a SQL server instance and compare it to a local copy, to automatically generate SQL commands to update the server so that the `XSD` in my program matches the server.

I've looked into Schema and system tables, but I feel as though the schema table is not where I should be looking because they seem to be a configuration of the collection that is the database. Where would I look to find this .Net `XSD` I search for?

Here are some places that have helped me in my research on this matter. I've published a long list of websites and small notes that may help others.
http://twentysixseconds.blogspot.com/2012/12/research-on-retrieving-xsd-from-sql.html

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps SQLMetal could help you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx

Specifically the /map output, this will generate a XML file of the database schema.

Hope this helps

Comment: Is there anyway to automate this through code though? I've already done research into the tool. I have not figured out how to automate the production of the mapping file so that I can generate the sql commands to correct the missing fields in the sql server.

Comment: I would use Process.Start() (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx), and then parse the XML

Comment: I need to perform these updates on the end users computer though. So I don't think this is an option I can use. Most of my clients won't have the tool installed.

Comment: can't you just package it with the rest of the application?